# align stack of images inside of SVG

Tags: css, image, svg

What is the best way to horizontally centre a stack of images which are inside of an SVG.

I have attempted opening image elements inside of a text element which has text-anchor middle. But I don't think I can embed elements inside of text.

The amount of images will vary between 1 and 5.

Comment: What do you mean by "horizontally centre"? Are you talking about aligning them in the SVG, or with CSS or what?

Comment: Aligned inside of the SVG, I don't mind if there is an SVG property to align them, or whether this would be best done with CSS.